# Boton con imagen variable en android studio

Tags: android-studio, xml, kotlin

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que hay un recyclerview y cada unos de sus items es un botón, en una de las propiedades del botón como podréis ver a continuación uso `android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/netflix_icon"` para poder tener un icono dentro del botón a la izquierda, lo que quiero hacer que no he conseguido es poder cambiar desde kotlin en función de un condicional la imagen que se le pone al botón, porque he visto que hay formas de manipular la propiedad background pero la que a mi me interesa es la de drawableLeft, agradecería que alguien me dijese como manipularla desde kotlin o bien otra forma de hacer un botón con el que pueda cambiar ese icono que sea similar al que os dejo aqui.

Boton en XML:

```html
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton_suscripcion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/borde_redondo"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/netflix_icon"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:includeFontPadding="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Y aquí os dejo una imagen de como quiero que quede y como esta actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar la propiedad `drawableLeft` llama al método `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` que tiene el botón y cambia la imagen por medio del parámetro correspondiente a `left`, así:

```
val button = //Aquí la referencia hacia el botón en cuestión
...
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.other_icon, 0, 0, 0)
```